# Javascript split with substring and include said substring in the produced array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, mathjax

I'm leveraging MathJax for a solution I'm building.  I'm using a placeholder—`\Box`—for a facts family equation.  I want to replace this placeholder when a solution based on a user's input.

Okay, so my question, given strings like these:

- `"\begin{array}{r} \Box\\ - \quad 7\\ \hline 6\end{array}"`
- `"\begin{array}{r} 12\\ - \quad \Box\\ \hline 1\end{array}"`
- `"\begin{array}{r} \Box\\ + \quad 1\\ \hline 6\end{array}"`
- *etc.*

`\Box` can show up in different spots in the string as you can see.

**The Goal**

I would like to evaluate the MathJax string and find `\Box`.  Once I find it I want to split at that point and then build an array that also includes `\Box` as one of the items in the array at the point for which it was found.

**Desired Outcome**

```
// With this string
    str = "\begin{array}{r} 12\\ - \quad \Box\\ \hline 1\end{array}"

// Find and split on '/Box' and include it.

// Desired Output
    ["\begin{array}{r} 12\\ - \quad ", "\Box", "\ \hline 1\end{array}"]
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to split it using regular expression

```
str.split(/(\\Box)/);
```

The parentheses will do the trick.

Comment: This will not include `\Box` in the Array.

Comment: Because of the backslash? See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394693/javascript-matching-backslash-in-a-string

Comment: Because split doesn't include the `separator` in the Array, only the `pieces` in which it breaks the string.

Comment: Try to run **console.log("\\begin{array}{r} 12\\\\ - \\quad \\Box\\\\ \\hline 1\\end{array}".split(/(\\Box)/));**

Comment: Ah, nevermind I just didn't see it was a regular expression.

Comment: `split` **does** include the separator in the resulting array--that's the "trick" the poster is referring to. It includes it because the regexp is included in a capture group.